# Verificar se um valor é Nulo no banco de dados

Tags: python, sql, django

Preciso de uma força, estou montando um sistema de controle de fluxo de caixa com Django, nesse sistema um "abro" um caixa com um ID, com o hora de abertura e a hora de fechamento eu deixo full, quando o usuário clicar em "fechar caixa" eu preciso verificar se o caixa tem o valor NULL para poder fechar, ou quando o usuário quiser abrir um caixa, precisa verificar se já tem um caixa aberto ou não, verificando o estado que vai estar o "fechamento do caixa" estou com dificuldade com fazer essa verificarão, alguém poderia me dar um forca

```
def novocaixa(request):
    forms = novocaixaForms(request.POST)
    if forms.is_valid():
        if (verificar se a hora de fechando continua null)  == null:
            messages.error(request, "ja possui um caixa aberto!")
        else:
            contexto = {'form':forms}
            ped = forms.save()
            return render (request, 'controlecaixa/index.html', contexto)
    return render (request, 'controlecaixa/index.html')
```

Comment: não seria só verificar só com `is None`? Seguindo as recomendações da [pep8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode pesquisar pelos caixas utilizando o "[filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/filters/)".

Exemplo:
`Caixa.objects.filter(dh_fechamento__isnull=True).exists()`

Isso irá retornar um boleano expressando se entre os 'Caixas' existe data de fechamento nula.

Dai para frente pode seguir com a lógica que desejar.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).